# DrawerNavigator cant set background to transparent whatever I do?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

I have spend more than si hours trying to change the background of the DrawerNavigator to transparent without any success.
When I write
when I change it in the main component it works

```
const MainTabBarDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
Home:{
    screen:MainTabNavigator,
},

},{
drawerWidth: 200,
drawerPosition: 'right',
// contentComponent: props => <Text style={{color:'white'}} >text 
</Text>,
drawerBackgroundColor: 'yellow',
//backgroundColor:'transparent',
// style: {
// //backgroundColor: 'transparent',
// flex: 1
// },
// contentOptions: {
//     style: {
//     backgroundColor: 'transparent',
//     flex: 1
// }


},
{
style: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        flex:1
}
}
)


class App extends Component{

render()
{
return(<MainTabBarDrawer style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}/>)
//return(<Login/>)
}

}
```

While the above approach will work my layout is much complex and I don't want the drawer to appear in all my views.
So dose any body know If I can change the background of the DrawerNavigator directly without rendering it as a component?

Answer (score 6):

In React Navigation 5, this would be:

```
<Drawer.Navigator
  initialRouteName={...}
  drawerContent={...}
  drawerStyle={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `drawerBackgroundColor: "transparent"` to drawerConfig.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `drawerContentOptions` or `drawerStyle` of `Drawer.Navigator`

```
 <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
         ..........
        drawerPosition="left"
        drawerContentOptions={{
          activeBackgroundColor:"transparent", //here change it     
        }}
        drawerStyle={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}} //or here
        initialRouteName="Splash">
        <Drawer.Screen        
          name="HomePage"
          component={StackScreen}
           
          options={{            
            drawerLabel: () => {return null},
            title:null,
            drawerIcon: () => {return <AppIconImage/>}
             
          }}
        />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed since I have updated to the latest version 
1.0.0-beta.16

Comment: this particular issue was actually solved in 1.0.0-beta.15

Answer (score 0):

For ReactNavigation Version 6.

try

```
    <Drawer.Navigator
     initialRouteName={...}
     drawerContent={...}
      screenOptions={{
        drawerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        },
      }}>
```

Adding React Docs link for reference.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator#drawerstyle

Comment: Only works on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the style `backgroundColor: 'transparent'` to **drawerStyle** inside the **screenOptions** param of **Drawer.Navigator** worked for me.

```
import React from 'react';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';

import CustomDrawer from '../components/Drawer';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const DrawerNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Stack"
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        drawerStyle: {width: '80%', backgroundColor: 'transparent'}, // Add this.
      }}
      drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawer {...props} />}>
      // Screens that go inside the navigator.
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};

export default DrawerNavigator;
```

**P.S.: I am using `@react-navigation/drawer: ^6.5.0`.**